# SP Previous year sales data from given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to  show current year data and previous Data in two column SQL Server 2000

Below Procedure shows my Given date Data I want to set Previous year data from given date in other column

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
  dbo.SI_Item.ig2_Code, dbo.SI_ItemGroup2.ig2_Desc,    
  SUM(SI_InvoiceDetail.invcd_Rate * dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcd_Qty -
      dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcd_DiscountAmt) AS Total
FROM
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail
INNER JOIN
  dbo.SI_Item ON dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.itm_ItemCode = dbo.SI_Item.itm_ItemCode
INNER JOIN
  dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster ON dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcm_CoCode = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_CoCode AND 
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcm_BrCode = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_BrCode AND 
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcm_SiteCode = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_SiteCode AND 
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcm_Year = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_Year AND 
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcm_Period = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_Period AND 
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.docs_DocCode = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.docs_DocCode AND 
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.doctyp_Code = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.doctyp_Code AND 
  dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.invcm_DocNo = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_DocNo
INNER JOIN
  dbo.SI_ItemGroup2 ON dbo.SI_Item.ig2_Code = dbo.SI_ItemGroup2.ig2_Code
WHERE  (dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.docs_DocCode = 'inv') AND 
       (dbo.SI_InvoiceDetail.itm_ItemCode BETWEEN '0101010000001' AND '0301020004001') AND
       (dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_Date BETWEEN @Invcm_date_from AND @Invcm_date_to)
GROUP BY dbo.SI_Item.ig2_Code ,SI_ItemGroup2.ig2_Desc
```

Comment: Two points: 1. The script looks enormous for quite a simple looking problem. I think, this fact may probably drive off some people who would otherwise try to answer your question. At least, using aliases for tables could make it simpler to understand. 2. Two examples would be very useful: one for what the script does and the other for what you want it to do, a great visual aid that would be. So much for the points. And if you applied them both, that might result in best and soonest solutions. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it 70% by changing in Query as below

SELECT     TOP 100 PERCENT   dbo.SI_Item.ig2_Code, dbo.SI_ItemGroup2.ig2_Desc,year(dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_Date) AS SalesYear,

&

Group By Year(dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_Date),dbo.SI_Item.ig2_Code ,SI_ItemGroup2.ig2_Desc

ORDER BY Year(dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_Date) ,dbo.SI_Item.ig2_Code

but its works but not as i want because its showing year in Row and User  mut inpuer date range of aboce 2 years then will show.

if anyone Got Proper solution do share please